# Load Kml on Google Maps javascript v3

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps-api-3, desktop-application

I am modifying a vb.net desktop project in which through a WebBrowser create a html file in which I use the Google Maps Javascript v3, to display a map in which among other things is needed to show a kml file roads, show them the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> <meta charset="utf-8">
<style type "text/css"> html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px}</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&key=KEY"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() { 
 var mapOptions = {zoom: 9, center: { lat: 13.775203, lng: -88.873150}};
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://localhost/Red_pavimentada.kml');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);


google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() { info5.open(map,marker1);});
}
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);  </script>
</head
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"> </div>
</body
</html>
```

Into ctaLayer i'm setting an url of kml file ubicated on my webserver local wamp, but i had add the next lines into apache file httpd.conf,because the webserver need to know the kind of file contains

```
AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml .kml
AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kmz .kmz
```

But it is not enough to load the kml on the map, what could be failing ?, what changes should do?

thank you for your help

Comment: Any javascript error, apache log, etc.?

Comment: Hi, it´s a good question, but Visually , there is no type of error, the storage of kml file could be a problem ?, where should physically have the kml file?

Comment: If you are hosting your kml on a server that's where the physical file would be. Also, not sure if that'll solve the issue but there shouldn't be any space before .kml in path so far as I know.